# HttpMethod getResponseBodyAsString is not recommended but why

Tags: java, performance, apache-httpclient-4.x

Was going through the Apache recommendations for HttpClient (http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html)
which mentions that

> **Response streaming:** It is recommended to consume the HTTP response body as a stream of bytes/characters using
>   HttpMethod#getResponseBodyAsStream method. The use of
>   HttpMethod#getResponseBody and HttpMethod#getResponseBodyAsString are
>   strongly discouraged.

But could not find the reason for the same. I am currently using getResponseBodyAsString with GetMethod and would like to know I am doing it wrong way?

Comment: Your question is answered in the text **directly above** the text you quote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation: "HttpClient is capable of efficient request/response body streaming. Large entities may be submitted or received without being buffered in memory."

The `getResponseBodyAsString` method requires HttpClient to buffer the entire response in memory. Basically you've giving the HTTP server an opportunity to crash your process by sending an enormous response.

But you gotta do what you gotta do. If your application requires that you handle the response as a `String` in memory, and you're sure that the response won't be too large (or you're willing to add a size check), then go for it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Wills. I think if the response is too large,it will even cause response delay other than process crash. Is that correct?

Comment: Well let's say the response is 20 gigabytes. That will take a while to receive, and then you'll probably get `OutOfMemoryError`, which will probably cause bad things to happen. At the very least, you won't be able to do whatever you were trying to do with the response. Worse, the out of memory condition can affect other threads in the same JVM and even other processes on the same host.

Comment: Is there a way to find this size limit (inflection point of the response size) which can "out of memory error"?

Comment: You should have some idea of what the maximum size of the response should be and plan around that. Most of the time everything will be fine. The documentation warning notwithstanding, it's totally normal to call a web service and read the response into memory. Huge responses are the exception not the norm. You probably don't have to worry unless you don't have control over the web service you're calling, like if the URL is provided by the user.